# Jenkins-slave "Cannot write to volume error" on kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am setting up my jenkins on kubernetes via helm to run my java deployment,

This spawns new pods for every build -> fair enough

Then I see that I need to store some maven jars which will be used by other builds,

So I came up with NFS installation and mounted it to /home/jenkins/.m2 via  jenkins configure (Web console)

Then I keep getting the

`error org.apache.maven.repository.LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException: Could not create local repository at /home/jenkins/.m2/repository`

I even tried

`securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000`
 
in the deployment.yaml

I tried adding

`USER root
RUN chown -R root /home/jenkins`

in the slave container

Its just not with the .m2 , slave is not able to write anything on this pvc.

At this point I’m confused where else the problem could be. 
can some one please help?

Comment: Did you maybe run out of space on the jenkins slave?

Comment: @herm No this is a error that says unable to write to the mounted volume, But the same can be written from the master

Comment: Did you install nfs-commons on the slave? Can you mount the nfs from outside docker and access files?

Comment: How did you share your nfs file system? by default nfs client mounts as nobody user. first you need to validate nfs share options.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. I solved this way:

- made own jnlp image, modified, with maven installed on it
- i moved m2 out of jenkins home directory into /opt/m2 through maven configuration
- created persistent disk, and bounded pv and pvc with it and mounted on /opt/m2 inside pod
- and last, I set inside Dockerfile for jnlp that User running image is ROOT, since every mount on kubernetes is mounted as root. Not very elegant but working solution